# Repeat dynamic pattern in column after amount is greater than X

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to create a savings spreadsheet where people save X amount of days in a week after they have reached X amount in income.

Can any Google Sheet experts help me achieve the following:

When the "amount" >= "min amount" (C1) then repeat the number of No's and Yes's according to the pattern (number of consecutive days) in B2 and B3

**Example image:**

[example google sheet image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWRhV.jpg)

**Example Google Sheet:**

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1n4Jg_uZUHBKi36S7HnkWWqqBTSTo3nKY9QgWP7wK9_o/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a possible solution.

```
={"SAVE:";ArrayFormula(if(A11:A52<C1,"NO",
{if(sequence(countif(A11:A52,"<"&C1)),);
array_constrain(flatten(split(concatenate(transpose(
if(sequence(1,countif(A11:A52,">="&C1)),
rept({"YES";"NO"}&"❄️",C2:C3)))),"❄️")),countif(A11:A52,">="&C1),1)}))}
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was trying to do. Thank you :)